# Как вставить код?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте требуется вставить большой кусок кода следующим образом:

```
var str = '<div class="block"> <label>Country :</label> <option value="0">Select Country</option> <div id="input"></div>';
```

так нет проблем, а при замене на:

```
<div class="block">
    <label>Country :</label>
    <select onchange="with (this) if (selectedIndex) location = options [selectedIndex].value" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    include('db.php');
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from user");
    $userlink = "http://msgphp/users/";
    $pphhpp = ".php";
    $sle = "/";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $country_name = $row['user'];
        echo '<option value="'.$userlink, $country_name, $sle, $country_name, $pphhpp.'">'.$row['user'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".country").change(function()
                    {
                        var country_id=$(this).val();
                        var post_id = 'id='+ country_id;
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax.php",
                            data: post_id,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(cities)
                            {
                                $(".city").html(cities);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            });
    </script>
    </select>
</div>
```

возникают проблемы из за того что как я понял не все переводит в текст. Можете помочь, как это устронить?

Comment: Откройте девтулс и приложите скриншот, где скрипт выставился текстом.

Comment: Я думаю это из-за того, что вы не подключили jQuery.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>